# Opening page on button click

Tags: android

I'm not sure why but the button doesn't work when clicked.  It just says that the activity has stopped working and then exits out of program.  Its being compiled with a level 8 api and targeting level 17 api.

```
    package com.example.button;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


public void open(MainActivity view) {
    view.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.org");
}

private void loadUrl(String string) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}


<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:onClick="open"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: Can you post the xml that goes with this java code?

Comment: post your xml , else no one can suggest you the fix for bug

Comment: ok i added it to the original copy

Answer (score 0):

```
public void open(MainActivity view) {
    view.loadUrl("http://www.yahoo.org");
}
```

`Activity` has no method `loadUrl`. Seems like you're trying to use a `WebView` here.

--

Still, this shouldn't crash the app since you're not calling `open` anywhere. Is this all your code?

Answer (score 0):

If your method open is used for the onClick property, set in the XML, then the parameters are incorrect. An onClick method should take `View view` not an activity like so:
XML:

```
<Button onClick="onClick"/>
```

Java:

```
public void onClick(View view)
{
    //do something when button is clicked
}
```

This view passed is the button which was clicked.
To open a specific url in a WebView use the following code in the onClick method:

```
 ((WebView)findViewById(android.R.id.WebView)).loadUrl("http://slashdot.org/");
```

More information on the WebView can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Answer (score 0):

where is the button?? where is the webview (is used when you are calling a webpage or url to view in your activity)?? share your code, also check android manifest file .. if you are moving from one activity to another activity need to mention there like this :

```
 <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SecondPage"
                    android:screenOrientation="landscape"
           android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
         </activity>
```